# MS SQL RegEx finding 6 numbers exactly

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to search a MS SQL database column for 6 numbers. The data in the column is a string of characters example:   **ab01234555cd0122abc987654efg**

Using RegEx : **[0-9]{6}**

Results are : **012345** and **987654**

Here is my current MS SQL code:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE seo LIKE '%[0-9]{6}%'`

The **{6}** does not work.

How can I use a regex qualifier to match the characters count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't actually have REGEX functionality. You would need to repeat the pattern six times:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE seo LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server `LIKE` is does not handle regular expressions, though it can do pattern matching. Since regexp is not supported, you cannot do things like `[0-9]{6}`. Instead, you need to repeat your pattern, which would look like this: `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

So your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE seo LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```